# Upload from git ReviewBoard showing "file not found in in repository"

Tags: git, review-board

I have only 1 file in my diff.
I tried

1. I used the similar technique that I was using previously.
2. done `git fetch; git rebase origin/master`, then created diff
3. create diff using `git diff HEAD > ~/temp/file.diff`
4. commit file locally and then `git format-patch --full-index origin/master` and created diff.

Still I'm getting the error while upload the diff to ReviewBoard.

Help?

Comment: Is it possible you never pushed that file? (just added and committed)